# Many to many relationship between two entities from different modules

Tags: module, microservices, many-to-many, circular-dependency, cycle

I am trying to create an application with 2 microservices. I have a spring boot app with two modules: device and user.
Now I need to make the following mapping: one user can have multiple devices and a device can belong to one or more users, so many to many relationship.
I got stuck because User is in one module and Device is in other module. To create the relationship I need to add cycle dependency between User and Device modules.

This is my User class from User module

```
package com.demo.user.entity;

import com.demo.device.entity.Device;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails{

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String role;
    private String password;

    public User(@Lazy Set<Device> devices){
        this.devices = devices;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_device",
    joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "device_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    })
    private Set<Device> devices;

    public User(String name, String role, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And this is my Device class from Device module

```
package com.demo.device.entity;

import com.demo.user.entity.User;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;

import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Device{

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String address;
    private int consumption;

    public Device(@Lazy Set<User> users){
        this.users = users;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "device", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getConsumption() {
        return consumption;
    }

    public void setConsumption(int consumption) {
        this.consumption = consumption;
    }
}
```

When I try to build the project, i get the following error:
**java: Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles.
Please ensure that all modules from cycle [device,user] are excluded from annotation processing**

I tried adding the @Lazy annotation but it's not working. I also tried to uncheck from properties "Enable annotation processing" but it keeps getting checked again on the next run...

Please help me!